# iOS revealing tableview header image (Parallax effect)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to set a large image that reveal more as the table view pulled further down,.. I know I'm not making any sense, it's easier to show [an example I recorded from netbot](http://vine.co/v/bdKrALdOheD).

Please let me know what the proper term for that and I'll update the title. (**Update:** apparently it's called parallax effect)

I've tried setting `UIImageView` to `self.tableView.backgroundView` and add transparent header for the first section. But it doesn't have the same feeling. it reveals from the top of the image instead of center, it's stretched and squashed on iPad portrait and iPhone landscape (I've tried all `contentMode`).

I also have tried setting `UIImageView` to the tableView header. Enabling `clipsToBounds` does show the center part of the image, but I can't get it to *reveal more* of the image.

An app called [My Artists](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/my-artists/id365565608?mt=8) also has this, but theirs don't bounce back. So, any idea how the brilliant devs at Tapbots approach this?

Comment: This project may be of some use: https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGParallelView

Comment: @TomIrving dude YES!! the option `ZGScrollViewStyleStickToTheTop` (The 3rd option in the segmented control from the demo project). and I believe he meant **ratio** instead of **radio**. Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: This project may be of some use: https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGParallelView

Comment: It seems [ZGParallelview](https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGParallelView) is no longer mantained, there is also this alternative FWIW. http://github.com/modocache/MDCParallaxView

Comment: I recently posted a blog post about accomplishing this using constraints which might help: http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/

Comment: You can use [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is weird. I'm pretty sure I've accepted an answer to this question. Anyway, the answer is [ZGExpandZoomView](https://github.com/zhigang1992/ZGExpandZoomView)