# Wrong constraints under iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to reproduce the parallax effect we can see everywhere nowadays, where, whenever you pull down a scrollview, an image reveals behind it ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385509/ios-revealing-tableview-header-image-parallax-effect)).

There's a bunch of solutions on the internet, but I'm trying to make it work using **auto layout only**. I saw someone got it working at a lightning talks a few days ago, but I guess I wasn't paying enough attention...

I got it working under iOS 7, however, under iOS 6, the image view doesn't stick to the top. Here's a sample projet with where I am right now : [DCParallaxHeader](https://github.com/DCMaxxx/DCParallaxHeader).

Another question is, is there any way to make the bottom view size's dynamic depending on the screen's size ? (As it it wrapped in a scrollview, and we must provided the contentSize using the constraints too ?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The person who make the talk wrote [a blog post](http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/) about it. Sums it all :-).